# In a package.json script, how do I pass an argument to node, as opposed to the script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I've got a script in my `package.json` that looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "... && mocha --full-trace test/db test/http test/storage test/utils",
```

I want to pass `--async-stack-traces` into mocha, but `--async-stack-traces` is a node command line argument, not a mocha command line argument.

I think I could achieve this by running `node --async-stack-traces node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --full-trace test/db test/http test/storage test/utils`, but something about that feels inelegant or non-idiomatic. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: This varies from bin to bin. I would open up node_modules/.bin/mocha and see how it invokes node. Usually it's pretty clear from that how to pass flags to node.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3060

Comment: Which is more or less the same as https://gustavostraube.wordpress.com/2016/08/22/passing-node-args-to-mocha-tests/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it is basically the way to do it:

```
node --async-stack-traces node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --full-trace test/db test/http test/storage test/utils
```

You can tidy it up a little bit by using `node_modules/.bin` like this:

```
node --async-stack-traces node_modules/.bin/mocha --full-trace test/db test/http test/storage test/utils
```

This next one probably isn't Windows compatibile and is not as easily understandable, but if you only support UNIX-like operating systems, you can rely on the `$PATH` injection of `npm` scripts to tidy it a bit more:

```
node --async-stack-traces `which mocha` --full-trace test/db test/http test/storage test/utils
```

If you don't want to rely on `whereis`, you can use `npm bin`:

```
node --async-stack-traces `npm bin`/mocha --full-trace test/db test/http test/storage test/utils
```

Hopefully at this point, you're throwing up your hands and going back to the first or second option above. (I recommend the second option, so you're not dependent on the `mocha` package layout, which conceivably could change.)